# Problemas al guardar con SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, android-studio, json, arrayadapter

tras comerme el coco un buen rato recurro a todos l@s developers del mundo, a ver si podéis ayudarme.

Estoy haciendo un repaso para un examen que tendré próximamente sobre fundamentos de la programación, en este caso lo estoy realizado todo para android y en lenguaje Java.

Os explico estoy realizando una app que se basa en escribir una nota (Con titulo y cuerpo). Dicha Activity obtiene esos datos y los envío a otra Activity. (Aquí os dejo la clase)

```
public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText title;
EditText body;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.note_layout);

    //encontramos vistas
    title = findViewById(R.id.titleET);
    body = findViewById(R.id.bodyET);

}

public void send(View view){

    Intent mainActivity = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

    //Obtenemos los datos
    String userInputTitle = title.getText().toString();
    String userInputBody = body.getText().toString();

    mainActivity.putExtra("titulo",userInputTitle);
    mainActivity.putExtra( "body",userInputBody);

    //Abrimos la siguiente activity
    startActivity(mainActivity);
}
```

En la siguiente Activity (MainActivity) cargo las sharedpreferences, recibo los datos del tipo string obtenidos e instancio un objeto de tipo Note. Una vez hecho esto lo añado al onjeto NoteList, que es un ArrayList de objetos Note. Por último lo guardo la lista con sharedpreferences utilizando la librería Gson y Utilizo un apadater personalizado para mostrar la el ArrayList en un ListView.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView list;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    NoteList noteList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = findViewById(R.id.list);


        load();

        addNote();

        save();


        //Utilizamos el adapter
        Adaptador adaptador = new Adaptador(this,R.layout.adapter_layout,noteList.notes);
        list.setAdapter(adaptador);


    }

    public void load () {

        //Cargamos las preferencias
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Lista de Notas", MODE_PRIVATE);

            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("notas", "");

            //Sentencia para evitar un NullPointerException por si lo recibe vacío
            if (!json.isEmpty()) {

                noteList = new NoteList();
                noteList.fromJson(json);

            } else {

                noteList = new NoteList();
            }
        }

    public void save () {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("notas", noteList.tojson());
        editor.apply();


    }



    public void addNote () {
        //Obtenemos datos
        Bundle title = getIntent().getExtras();
        String titleS = title.getString("titulo");

        Bundle body = getIntent().getExtras();
        String bodyS = body.getString("body");
        //Instanciamos objeto
        Note note = new Note();
        note.setTitulo(titleS);
        note.setBody(bodyS);

        //Añadimos objeto a la lista
        noteList.notes.add(note);

    }


    public void Write (View view){
        //Abrimos NoteActivity
        Intent NoteActivity = new Intent(this, com.example.notas.NoteActivity.class);
        startActivity(NoteActivity);

    }
```

Por si fuera necesario os dejo el resto de clases por aquí
Os dejo el Adaptador por aquí:

```
 public class Adaptador extends ArrayAdapter {


    Context context;
    int itemLayout;
    ArrayList<Note>objects;

    public Adaptador(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<Note>objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);

        this.context = context;
        this.itemLayout = resource;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(itemLayout,parent,false);
        TextView titleIT= view.findViewById(R.id.titleIT);
        titleIT.setText(objects.get(position).getTitle());
        TextView descriptionIT = view.findViewById(R.id.descriptionIT);
        descriptionIT.setText(objects.get(position).getBody());

        return view;
    }
```

Aquí os dejo la clase NoteList:

```
public class NoteList {

public ArrayList<Note>notes;

public NoteList(){
    notes = new ArrayList<>();
}

public String tojson(){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(this);
    return json;
}

public NoteList fromJson(String json){
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    NoteList noteList = gson.fromJson(json,NoteList.class);
    return noteList;
}
```

Y por último la clase Note:

```
public class Note {
    private String title;
    private String body;

    public void setTitulo(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
```

Cualquier consejo que incluso no tenga que ver con la duda es bienvenido, estoy empezando y cualquier tip es de gran ayuda.

Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: Comparte la clase mainActivity

Comment: Pero, no se recomienda guardar Notas en `SharedPreferences`, ¿por qué elegiste eso? `SharedPreferences` es generalmente para guardar datos sobre la configuración, pares clave valor como `{color: red, size: 10}` cosas así. ¿Por qué no usas un archivo, un JSON por ejemplo?

Answer (score 0):

Al guardar y al salvar la preferencia te sugiero abras el archivo de preferencias definiendo su nombre.

Lo adecuado es usar un nombre de preferencias sin espacios ya que este será usado como una variable que será asignado al archivo de preferencias.

Realiza los siguientes cambios:

```
   public void load () {

        //Cargamos las preferencias
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Lista_de_Notas", MODE_PRIVATE);

            String json = sharedPreferences.getString("notas", "");

            //Sentencia para evitar un NullPointerException por si lo recibe vacío
            if (!json.isEmpty()) {

                noteList = new NoteList();
                noteList.fromJson(json);

            } else {

                noteList = new NoteList();
            }
        }

    public void save () {

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("Lista_de_Notas", MODE_PRIVATE);

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("notas", noteList.tojson());
        editor.apply();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

En la clase `NoteActivity`, dentro del método `onCreate()`, nunca estas llamando el método `send(View view)` por lo que los datos nunca se envian, ahora si ese método pertenece a un evento `onClick`, te falta implementar el `View.OnClickListener` en la clase:

```
public class NoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

De igual forma sucede con la clase `MainActivity`, dentro del método `onCreate()`, llamas a todos los métodos menos a `Write(View view)`, y si ese método pertenece a un evento de `onClick` te falta implementar el `View.OnClickListener` en la clase:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener
```

**RECOMENDACIONES**

Trata de usar `commit()` en ves de `apply()` ya que `apply()` es asíncrono y estarias queriendo obtener los datos antes de que se terminen de guardar y eso te daria como resultados vacios o nulos.

Comment: Gracias, he implentado los cambios pero sigue igual. El problema es que al mostrar la lista que generó solo me muestra lo ultimo que he escrito, no me muestra toda la lista